# Sonarqube doesn't accept my test but it works in my Eclipse

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have the following code. It creates a digital clock for 10 seconds.
And when i'm doing commit in git SonarQube says that all my tests were failed there. But it works on my PC :\

```
public final class Clock implements Runnable {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Clock.class);
    private static JFrame                 frame  = new JFrame();
    private final Font                    clockFont;
    private volatile boolean              flag   = true;


    /**
     * Clock constructor.
     */

    public Clock() {

        Clock.frame.setSize(1000, 250);
        Clock.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Clock.frame.setVisible(true);
        Clock.frame.setResizable(false);

        this.clockFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40);

        final Container contentArea = Clock.frame.getContentPane();
        final ClockPanel timeDisplay = new ClockPanel();

        contentArea.add(timeDisplay);
        Clock.frame.setContentPane(contentArea);

    }
```

Main method

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Clock clock = new Clock();
        final Thread thread = new Thread(clock);
        thread.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Clock.LOGGER.info("Interrupted Exception was thrown", e);
        }

        clock.stopRunning();
        Clock.LOGGER.info("program was successfully executed");
    }
```

timeWashington method

```
    public static String timeWashington() {

        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

        final String month = new SimpleDateFormat("M", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now.getTime());
        final int date = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
        final int hrs = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int min = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        final int sec = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        return date + ", " + month + ", " + hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " - Washington";
    }
```

and continuation of the code

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (this.flag) {
            Clock.frame.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                Clock.LOGGER.info("Interrupted Exception was thrown", e);
            }

        }
        Clock.frame.setVisible(false);
        Clock.frame.dispose();

    }

    /**
     * stopRunning method.
     */
    public void stopRunning() {
        this.flag = false;
    }

    /**
     * The ClockPanel fills current panel
     */
    class ClockPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics painter) {

            painter.setFont(Clock.this.clockFont);
            painter.setColor(Color.black);
            painter.drawString(Clock.timeWashington(), 40, 40);
        }
    }

}
```

And my Junit tests are as follows:

```
public class ClockTest {

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void testMain() throws InterruptedException {
        final String[] args = null;
        Clock.main(args);
        Assert.assertEquals("it should be  equal", "program was successfully executed",
                this.log.getLog());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTimeWashington() {

        boolean result = false;
        final String time = Clock.timeWashington();
        if ((time != null) && !time.isEmpty()) {
            result = true;
        }

        Assert.assertTrue("This will succeed.", result);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how i can fix it.

Failed
ClockTest.testRunClock

Last 1 build failed (With Unstable # 288)
It took 2 ms.

Error message
Could not initialize class by.iba.gomel.Clock
Call stack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class by.iba.gomel.Clock
    at by.iba.gomel.ClockTest.testRunClock(ClockTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.LogPrintStream$1$1.evaluate(LogPrintStream.java:30)
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.PrintStreamHandler$3.evaluate(PrintStreamHandler.java:48)
    at org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.internal.LogPrintStream$1.evaluate(LogPrintStream.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: Including the failure details would be helpful.

Comment: I am guessing that you have a different logging configuration in the git build. The logs are not written to System.out.

Comment: I just added the failure details for testRunClock()

Comment: What is `by.iba.gomel.Clock`? Is it a class in your project or is it a dependency? Is it related to `Clock1`? Also in your CI, why do you allow the SonarQube analysis if your unit tests failed? You shouldn't.

Comment: I used just Clock everywhere. I wrote Clock1 in code only here. Sorry for missleading. My Junit tests in Eclipse are succeed.

Answer (score 0):

the root problem seems to be that your test is looking for class 'Clock':

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class by.iba.gomel.Clock
```

But your implementation is `Clock1`

This implies to me that where you are running your tests is out of date compared to your local machine.

(i.e. either the rename from Clock to Clock1 or the associated update to your test case have not made it to where your test is being run)

Comment: I used just Clock everywhere. I wrote Clock1 in code only here. Sorry for missleading. That's definitely not the problem :\